Using pdfjs-dist Inside WXT Service Worker: "import() is disallowed on ServiceWorkerGlobalScope"
Here's my code that loads the pdf library and setup workerSrc.
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;

export default defineBackground(() => { 

browser.downloads.onCreated.addListener(function (downloadItem) {
   // download this url and get data
   const pdfDoc = pdfjsLib.getDocument(await blob.arrayBuffer()).promise;
    const pages = (await pdfDoc).numPages;
    console.log("[parseFileContent]: pdf pages: ", pages);

}

}


I also added this code in my config file
export default defineConfig({
  modules: ["@wxt-dev/module-react"],
  manifest: {
    permissions: ["downloads", "webRequest", "tabs", "storage"],
    host_permissions: [
      "*://*.amazonaws.com/*",
      "*://*.amazoncognito.com/*",
    ],
    web_accessible_resources: [
      {
        resources: ["pdf.worker.js"],
        matches: ["<all_urls>"],
      },
    ],
  },
  extensionApi: "chrome",
});


I tried using the code above after searching many stackoverflow questions.

I solved this problem by passing the processing task to an offscreen where we can initialize the global worker for pdfjs.
The reason it doesn't work in background.ts is that the library calls some dynamic imports() in its code so it will never work in background.ts.
